# objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable"

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page controller="Soqlexample3" sidebar="true" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="opportunity">
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
               <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!search}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionitem>
                <apex:outputField value="Enter Name"/>
                <apex:inputfield value= "{!opporName}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionitem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionitem>
            <apex:outputField value="enter type"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!opporType}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionitem>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

> Error message: "Could not resolve the entity from `<apex:inputField>` value binding '{!opporName}'.  `<apex:inputField>` can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable".

Comment: `{!opporName}` in your page is not resolving to a VF property that is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `apex:inputField` and `apex:outputField` must resolve to an sobject's field. Instead, you probably meant to use `apex:inputText` and `apex:outputLabel`, respectively.

If you wanted to use the field elements, you'd attach them to fields:

```
<apex:page controller="Soqlexample3" sidebar="true" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="opportunity">
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
               <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!search}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:inputfield value= "{!opp.Name}"/> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!opp.Type}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Where `opp` is:

```
public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
```